# Rephrasing the following sentences correctly

Tags: comparison

I have the following sentences to be rephrased according to the word in brackets (by the way, I consider them to be related by the same thematics - comparisons so that they are involved in the same post):

> 1. That's the silliest thing I've ever heard. (NEVER)
> 2. Sam makes the same amount of money as Joe. (MUCH)
> 3. I run faster than Laura. (DOESN'T)
> 4. This book is much more interesting than that one. (LESS)

Please, take a look at the following I've put down:

> 1. I've never heard sillier thing!
> 2. Sam makes as much money as Joe does.
> 3. Laura doesn't run faster than me.
> 4. That book is far less interesting than this one.

Although I've written the above, I can't still make out if they are completely correct. They seem to be well-written for me but still.

Maybe the following would sound better or both variants are possible:

> 1. I've never heard such a silly thing!
> 2. Sam makes as much money as Joe.
> 3. Laura doesn't run as fast as me/Laura doesn't run as fast as I do.
> 4. That book is much less interesting than this one.

Comment: "much less" appears wrong in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your sentences are fine, except for "I've never heard sillier thing" which is missing an "a":

> I've never heard **a** sillier thing

or

> I've never heard anything sillier.

Otherwise all of the sentences are a bit *artificial*, but that's not uncommon with language exercises when you're forced to adopt some predefined pattern.